# Replace specific lines in one file with data contained in another file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I want to replace specific lines in one file (File 1) with data contained in another file (File 2). For example:
File 1 (Input code):

```
 other lines...
 11 !!! Regular Expression
 10 0.685682*100
 11 0.004910*100
 12 0.007012*100
 13 0.146041*100
 14 0.067827*100
 15 0.019460*100
 16 0.019277*100
 17 0.001841*100
 18 0.047950*100
 other lines...
```

File 2 (to add new data):

```
 1 0.36600*100
 2 0.44466*100
 3 0.0.046*100
 4 0.15544*100
 5 0.16600*100
 6 0.14477*100
 7 0.01927*100
 8 0.00188*100
 9 0.05566*100
```

How could I replace the Input data (File 1) from line 1 to line n with the data contained in File 2 (data). I tried using `sed` as follows:

```
sed '/!!! Regular Expresion/r File2' File1
```

and I get the following:

```
 1 !!! Regular Expression
 2 0.36600*100
 3 0.44466*100
 4 0.0.046*100
 5 0.15544*100
 6 0.16600*100
 7 0.14477*100
 8 0.01927*100
 9 0.00188*100
 10 0.05566*100
 11 0.685682*100
 12 0.004910*100
 13 0.007012*100
 14 0.146041*100
 15 0.067827*100
 16 0.019460*100
 17 0.019277*100
 19 0.001841*100
 20 0.047950*100
```

My problem is that this command can insert the lines contained in File 2 but not replace them. How can I replace only these lines (from 10 to 18) with the new data?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, do kindly do add your efforts in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Please @Yro, review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should add a verifiable example of what you tried. If not it will be flagged as OFF-TOPIC. Read point 3 on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Please, help us to help you.

Comment: Are you just trying to replace data in the second column, or do you want to completely replace lines 1 to N?  If the latter: `{ cat file2; sed -e 1,${N}d file2; } > output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> replace specific lines in one file from 10 to 18 with the data contained in File 2

Lets use dynamic programming and split "replacing" into "deleting" and "inserting".

> [Delete] specific lines in one file from 10 to 18

That's easy:

```
sed '10,18d'
```

would delete lines from 10 to 18.

> [Insert] the data contained in File 2 [to line 10]

That's also easy:

```
sed '9r file2'
```

It appends the content of file2 after line 9, so first line of file2 is the new line 10.

All together:

```
sed '10,18d; 9r file2'
```

Example:

```
# seq 8 | sed '3,6d; 2r '<(seq -f 2%.0f 5)
1
2
21
22
23
24
25
7
8
```